# Issue importing psycopg2 after installing from local archives (in order to specify pg_config path in setup.cfg)

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to install and use psycopg2, using Python on Mac OS. After running into issue with install due to "pg_config not found" error, I downloaded source files and specified `pg_config` path in setup.cfg. Installation was successful but now psycopg2 encounters an error when imported.

#### Install

```
pip install /Users/k/Downloads/psycopg2-2.8.3
Processing ./Downloads/psycopg2-2.8.3
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.8.3
```

#### Import error

```
import psycopg2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                     # noqa
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If me, I would rather do it as follows:

```
$ pip install pipenv --user
$ pipenv shell
$ pipenv install psycopg2==2.8.3
$ python
>>> import psycopg2
```